# How to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in JDBC (Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp

In MY_TABLE, when ORD_AMT field is updated then LST_UPDT_TS is updated with current_timestamp too. Presented by following query:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET ORD_AMT = 50, LST_UPDT_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ORD_ID = 'ORD_123'
```

I need implement this business by JDBC code, and my Web server and DB server are difference timezone. If I pass Date().getTime() to JDBC, it's the current of Web server but I need the current time of DB server.

Is there a way for passing CURRENT_TIMESTAMP like this:

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateOrderSql);
preparedStatement.setFloat(1, 50);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
preparedStatement.setString(3, 'ORD_123');
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't pass `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a parameter. Just keep the keyword in your SQL and don't replace it with a `?`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the current timestamp parameter to oracle, you can make use of `SYSTIMESTAMP` like below

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET ORD_AMT = 50, LST_UPDT_TS = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHERE ORD_ID = 'ORD_123'
```

ultimately both might be same if **FRONT END** server and **DB** server are in same machine, i mean single tier architecture. If not you can type cast it to string and store the same in table with **`varchar2`** datatype.

Comment: I would almost never recommend storing date/timestamps as varchar, you can pass it as string though an call a corresponding function to cast via dbms, i.e. `LST_UPT_TS = to_date( :dateAsString, 'DD.MM.YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

To update **LST_UPDT_TS** field with JDBC use the following code:

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

And you'll see in DB updated **LST_UPDT_TS** field.